# "Спустя" в значении "после"

Tags: предлоги

Возможна ли следующая конструкция?

Прошла неделя спустя день рождения.

Comment: Рождение (по типу Кофе) — не склоняется?

Comment: Исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Нет, такая конструкция безграмотна. После "спустя" должен стоять промежуток времени, который прошел, а не какой-то момент в прошлом.